# JAX-RS and character encoding problems

Tags: java, web-services, character-encoding, jax-rs

I am using Jax RS and have simple POST WS, that takes InputStream, that contains MIME message (xml + file).

The MIME message is in UTF-8, file contained as a body part is an email message in MIME RFC 822 in ISO-8859-1 encoding, that I'm converting to PDF using Aspose.

When running as a webservice, the resulting PDF has incorrect characters (ø, å etc.). But when I tried to use the exact input, but reading it from file instead and call the method with FileInputStream, the resulting PDF is OK.

Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/documents/convert/{flag}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String convertFile(InputStream input, @PathParam("flag") String flag) throws WebApplicationException {

    FileInfo info = convertToPdf(input);
    return info.getResponse();
}
```

If I run this as webservice it produces PDF with incorrectly encoded characters with "box" instead of some charcters (such as ø, å etc.). When I run the the same code with the same input by by calling

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
convertFile(fis);
```

the resulting PDF has correct encoding (the WS is run on server, testing with file is done on my local machine).

Could this be incorrect setting of locale on the server?

Comment: Can you please provide more details?  I suspect the problem may have to do with the CharSets specified when you are doing various operations.  Can you please edit your question to provide snippets of code for the client where you are reading the message, where you are converting it to a PDF, where you are uploading it, and where you are downloading it to view?

Comment: What's the difference between `convertToPdf` and `convertFile`? Is the return type the same?

Comment: No, convertToPdf does more than convertFile, I omitted that for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an `InputStreamReader` to read the `FileInputStream` ? If so, did you initialize it using the 2-parameters constructor, with `CharSet.forName("UTF-8")` as the second argument ? (as you mentionned the incoming stream is already in UTF-8) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tell the container that it's UTF-8.

something like...

```
@Produces("text/plain; charset=utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your local file and you MIME message body are not encoded the same way.
Your post states that the file is encoded in ISO-8859-1.

If you are using an `InputStreamReader` (as Xavier Coulon's is suggesting) you should pass the expected encoding to it. In this case

```
CharSet.forName("ISO-8859-1")
```

If this does not help, could you please provide the content of the `convertToPdf(InputStream is)` method